# Microsoft Office version to have DCOM Object

Tags: ms-word, com, dcom

I'm trying to work on office COM Object.
But after installing Office, I can't find COM word object in DCOMCNFG.exe.
After some time spent searching the right version of Office, I've read that DCOM Object Are available only with Enterprise Version for Windows Server 2008:

[image]

I'm working on Windows Server 2012, so do I need to buy the Enterprise version ?

Comment: You need to install Office to get Office COM objects, whatever the Windows version you run.

Comment: @SimonMourier after installing office, COM Object are not on the DCOMCNFG. that's why I was wondering if the version could influence it.

Comment: I don't think so. What object exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Exactly, I want to use Excel, PowerPoint and Word to make a thumbnail/convert in PDF

Comment: What are the objects exactly? CLSID? AppId?

Comment: Even CLSID are not in the DCOMCNFG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix my problem.
It wasn't caused by the version, but the installation.
First, I tried with an ISO of office, with this, I didn't have COM object.
But by using the executable you can download online, I ended up having my DCOM object.

Server: Windows Server 2012
Office version: Office 2016

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that MS doesn't recommend automating Office applications on the server side, here is what they state:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround, if you deal only with open XML documents, you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for the intro. Another alternative is third party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: I already know that. But currently, the fact is, I want to use Office COM objects to convert document into pdf, but they're not installed